# add text dynamically li in accordion jquery Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

i have a jquery accordion menu. i work with coldfusion. with an AJAX function, i have my data for my menu. With Coldfusion, i created several dynamic li with a different id. and with jquery or javascript, i would like to fill my li

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li>
        <a href="##">Test</a>
        <ul>
            <!--- It's my big query -->
            <cfloop query="cat">
                <li id="#cat.id#">
                    <cfquery  name="cat2">
                    <!--- I have remove query but query is ok -->
                    </cfquery>
                    <cfif #cat2.recordcount# neq 0>
                        <ul>
                            <cfloop query="cat2">
                                <li id="#cat2.id#"></li>
                            </cfloop>
                        </ul>
                    </cfif>
                </li>
            </cfloop>
        </ul>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

My first li are ok. with jquery i can to fill my li with that : 
`$("#"+my_id_li).html(value[i][1])`
but for my second li no text appears

my id li are ok and data are ok

I don't know why my second li doesn't appears in my menu

Comment: can you show ur code in jsfiddle ??

Comment: with coldfusion it's possible ?

Comment: -1 For a client-side question like this one, your server-side code is not very helpful. A sample of the generated HTML **as seen by your browser** and the JS/JQ code you're using would be most helpful. :)

Comment: Your second query has `name=idpcat`.  However nowhere else in your code refers to that query name.  Instead you're using `cat2`

Answer (score 0):

with my AJAX page, i created a table with all necessary data. In javascript i use my table for to fill my li. it's my function :

```
Info('fr');
function Info(langue)
{
  var obj = langue;
  var instance = new proxy2();
  instance.setCallbackHandler(getSuccess);
  instance.getDataC(obj);
}



function getSuccess(value){
var i = 0;
while(i<value[0][10])
{ 
  $("#"+value[i][50]).html(value[i][1]);
  i++ 
}
```

}